# npm link is not working with angular-cli created projects

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli, npm-link

I have created a project using `angular-cli`. There is one `AppModule` and `AppComponent` I want to use this `AppModule` and its components (`AppComponent`) in other angular apps. So I have created `index.ts` file and exported the `AppModule` and `AppComponent`

```
export {AppModule} from './src/app/app.module';
export {AppComponent} from './src/app/app.component';
```

Then created local linking using `npm link` and a link is created with the name defined in package.json.

Now In other project where I want to use this exported module run the

```
npm link project-name
```

Linking has been done successfully. 
I tried

```
import { AppModule as AModule} from 'my-components';
```

But this is not working as webpack gets failed to compiles AppModule file as the reference is not getting resolved. In SystemJs We defined the mapping of this in systemjs.config.js file but there is no config file.

How can I solve this?

Is there any other method to reuse local modules?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: still not :( . will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able. Let me quote

> We don't support Library building with the CLI right now. We do
>   support linking libraries built properly inside a CLI application.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9273

Comment: Take a look here. I think the tgz alternative is much less of a headache. at least for the most part it seems to have less issues. https://dev.to/vishesh/creating-new-angular-library-and-publishing-it-in-npm-5f3g

Comment: This answer is no longer valid

Answer (score 11):

In Angular 7, `"preserveSymlinks": true`

It worked for me: project > architect > build > options

Comment: same for angular 13, this saves my day

Answer (score 9):

Add the following to your `tsconfig.json` of the host application you are loading the npm-linked lib into.

```
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]
    }
```

Apparently the linked packages can't use peer dependancies normally. This will force the library to use your app's node_modules/@angular/* libs, which is what happens when you `npm install` the lib.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!! you're my hero

Comment: This to me hours to find :(

Comment: This was the last thing I needed to fix my link errors, along with preserveSymlinks.

Comment: The better question is _why has this not been fixed by the Angular team_?

Answer (score 3):

It's working now with a  `"preserveSymlinks": true` in your angular.json.

just add it there : project > architect > build.

Answer (score 1):

this is a hot topic at the moment which seems not yet soloved completey. I got to the following information:

Linking lib created by the angular cli ist not that easy. You can read in the docs

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-linked-library

I was able to make it work by following the comment provided by nimaen in this post https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3875

--BR
Dennis

Comment: I still have this problem and I can't solve it with that solution provided in the issues pages, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the links to the projects to `tsconfig.js` file for any modules that you want to work in the source code form.

Note that the module alias must be a pointer to a TypeScript file without `ts` or `js` extension, not to the directory of `package.json` file.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "my-third-party-package": [
        // Can be project root relative path or abs path on your hd
        "projects/my-third-party-package/src/index"
      ],
    }
  },
}
```